# Running an ios project with podfile

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been searching for camera ios open source app, and found some several apps from github. I will make those open source apps as my reference in building a project for the company I'm working for. I am, again, a noob ios developer, my 4th day today. I used to be a C# and windows user. I'm knowledgeable how to build and run xcode projects in my iphone and ipad, knowledgeable to build a ui with controls programmatically.

I would like to run this open source app: https://github.com/danielebogo/DBCamera

But it has a podfile or something, and when I try to run the example project, xcode returns me some errors about the shell script, podfile something.

I've read the description of the project. It says there: "If you use the example project, run pod install to install GPUImage dependency"...

So I opened up my terminal (console), and then changed directory to the example folder. typed "pod install" but the terminal is I think being stucked at "Running dependencies"...

My question is: Am I doing it right? or do I have to download and install cocoapods? https://cocoapods.org/   I have no idea how to run the example project. I just wanna see how it works before I study the codes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you opened the `xxx.xcodeproj` , if your project contains podfile then your project make sure to open the `.xworkspace`file.

> The project.xcworkspace file gets created if you use Cocoa Pods (pod install). It creates a pods workspace and you'll need to open the project.xcworkspace file instead of the project file moving forward if you want what you just installed via Pods.

if you want to know about cocoa pods , see this [guidelines](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2)

Comment: if you open the .xworkspace the error does not appear

Comment: Hoooray! Cheers Anbu! Thank you so much! Yeah, I opened the proj file not the workspace file! Stackoverflow is a great place to seek help. I can't just ask my senior devs here in the office, they are very busy and probably will just tell me to google it. I already did.

Comment: @user5295097 -- happy to meet with you , no body genius compare to google , whenever u need try in google , if you are get the result show the tried code to your seniors , then those are find the way to resolve , this is the correct way to learn , you can learn yourself automatically

Answer (score 1):

you need to follow below steps to install cocoa pod into your project. I have attached images with steps to configure pod.
[image: Step One]

[image: Step Two]

Comment: Thanks for this Dipen. Anbu is correct, I opened the xcodeproj file instead of workspace. Wow. I didn't know about this.